# Get all the Facebook user which use the application.

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I develop a Facebook application where i implemented the login with Facebook accounts using "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,picture&access_token=xxxxxx" end point from the Facebook API. With the data receive to the Facebook I created an user in my database where I can login with this.
Now, I must will get all the users Facebook which use the my Facebook application. There are a Facebook end point where i can receive from the API all the users Facebook in the JSON format ?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I must will get all the users Facebook which use the my Facebook application. There are a Facebook end point where i can receive from the API all the users Facebook in the JSON format ?

No, there is not. You only get user ids when they log in – to store them appropriately for whatever purpose you need them for, is your responsibility.